# Embedding TTF in Java failed

Tags: java, fonts, jframe, truetype

I'm trying to embed a ttf-font in a JFrame. Of course I searched a lot in various threads. I've tried the following snippet:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("abc.ttf");
Font myFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
Font abcFont = myFont.deriveFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,40);
```

In the second line (`Font myFont = ...`) eclipse is showing the following errors:

```
Multiple markers at this line:
-unhandled exception type IOException
-unhandled exception type FontFormatException
```

Hope you know a solution!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You must set **40F** if You want set size as 40.